# Find out what is causing an java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I've built a Java application that is started by Java Web Start.

In a final stage of the application it uploads a file to our server.

Recently I've started getting crashes on Mac OSX (10.6).

I get this from the log:

```
MRJ Plugin for Mac OS X v1.0.1
[starting up Java Applet Security @ Thu Apr 14 17:58:16 CEST 2011]
Thu Apr 14 17:58:20 CEST 2011 JEP creating applet ScratchApplet (http://scratch.mit.edu/static/misc/)
<<< ProxyClassLoader: defined LiveConnectProxy class. >>>
<<< Here're the permissions you've got: >>>
<<< java.security.Permissions@57b13a (
 (java.net.SocketPermission scratch.mit.edu connect,accept,resolve)
)
 >>>
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkAccess(AppletSecurity.java:235)
    at sun.plugin.security.ActivatorSecurityManager.checkAccess(ActivatorSecurityManager.java:155)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:336)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:564)
    at jep.AppletFrame.destroyAppletDirectly1(Unknown Source)
    at jep.AppletFrame$Destroy1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:639)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:637)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:653)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:651)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:650)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

This tells the that it's a security issue. But the strange thing is that I have no problems on windows and this is present in the jnlp file:

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

Its a signed application.

How can I find out more about where the exeption is thrown?

I also have the crashdump available, but Im unsure how to interpet it.

Comment: Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  What else does the app. do that requires trust?

Comment: Its a screenrecorder that writes files and the sends it to our server

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if you app is signed properly.  You can test the jar file using the following command line:

```
jarsigner -verify <jarfile>
```

Try that on both windows and mac.  Compare the output to see if it's validating the same on Windows as Mac.  You need to have the certificate of the certificate authority in the cacerts file in the JVM.  Since Apple is in charge of delivering Java on Mac that file might not contain the same certificate authorities as windows because that's distributed by Oracle.  Supposedly in the near future Oracle will be delivering Java on Mac, but that could be the problem.  Essentially your app doesn't have the permissions you have requested as your exception says.